# Update FireStore Document on Read

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React and Firestore to make a Blog like site. Each Post is Stored as a separate document in Post collection.

The Document structure looks like :

```
--Posts
     --Post1
           --title
           --body
           --views
           --likes
     --Post2
           --title
           --body
           --views
           --likes
```

I want to update the views whenever someone Views a post. What is the best way to Achieve this in Firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many cases you would use [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) directly. However since you're incrementing a counter you should also use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to prevent race conditions when multiple users are trying to increment it around the same time:

```
// Create a reference to the post.
const postRef = db.collection('Posts').doc('<postId>');

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(postRef).then(function(post) {
      if (!post.exists) {
        throw new Error('Post does not exist!');
      }

      const newViews = post.data().views + 1;
      transaction.update(postRef, { views: newViews });
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Transaction successfully committed!');
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Transaction failed: ', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("Posts").update(
  { views: FieldValue.increment(1) }
  { exists: true }
);
```